# PHP - Display and compare two nested arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a code like this:

```
function displayArrayRecursively($arr, $indent='') {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                //
                displayArrayRecursively($value, $indent . '--');
            } else {
                //  Output
                echo "$indent $value \n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to use it for two nested and multidimensional arrays and compare them.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

ou can also use this php function

**array-diff-key()**

and please refer URL: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php

Comment: This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array. I have 2 n-dimensional arrays with different types of keys like array or object. I want to compare these arrays and remove only items that have same keys and values.